# Any I.i.d sequence of random variables are uniformly integrable

Tags: real-analysis, probability

This is an exam question. My teacher says it is true. But I'm thinking it might be false for random variables such as Cauchy. Can anyone confirm that this is false in general?

Comment: If a sequence of random variables is uniformly integrable, then in particular each random variable in the sequence is integrable.  This follows almost immediately from the definition.  So indeed any non-integrable distribution is a counterexample to the claimed statement.  The author of the question probably meant to say "integrable random variables" but forgot.

Answer (score -1):

I think Cauchy distribution would be fine because it is bounded. In general I think it is true, you can take the maximum point of the distribution to use with your delta in your epsilon-delta proof.

Also, given that all the distributions are the same, you can of course bound the absolute integrals. The absolute integrals are the same as the usual integral as the pdfs are positive functions.

Comment: Tail of Cauchy integrates to infinity.

Comment: agree my mistake